# Windows Event Collector Filtering

Tags: windows-event-log

Afternoon and thanks for taking the time to read my question!

I am testing WEC and have got it where the source device sends the logs to my collector but with some strange behavior. Both the collector and source are running WS19. What I am seeing when I configure which Event IDs to monitor instead of collecting all, if there are more than two IDs in the list, the source device shows subscribing to the subscription but then immediately unsubscribes, if its less than three events(1 or 2), it stays subscribed. Now the funny thing is if I am monitoring for event 4624 which is in that filter for the unsubscribed subscription, it does forward the event, why would it send if its not subscribed and is this normal behavior?

Also, I've learned that if I put more than 22 event ids in the filter for the subscription, it will not send the events at all. I've had to create four subscriptions to accomplish what I need as I am collecting 48 events only.

Just trying to figure this out, doesn't seem to be a lot of threads out there around this and I haven't found any MS documentation about how many one can use per subscription.

Comment: The 22 boolean limit for event ids in the Windows query language Xpath filter has been known since at least 2009. Known limitation.

Comment: Thanks, figured it had to be something there. Found one guy saying to combine but it sounds like that wont work either. Is it normal for the client to report unsubscribed but still forward events? If it is, sounds like I can keep moving forward. Just trying to figure things out before I go to pulling in more clients.

Comment: hard to say without seeing the XML and configuration.

Comment: My preferred approach is to include all events from the target channel and then use suppress statements to tune out the noise. Then keep tuning your subscriptions over time.

Comment: Cool thought, didn't think about using that approach.

Comment: I know this is off topic, but while I'm here, should one include a loop-back IP in the ipv4 filter? Just dropped the log collector in the group to test(this will be a domain-wide policy) and its complaining about not being able to connect, I can open powershell and test the connection and its able to find itself on :::1 even though I dont have the ipv6 option enabled. I also added another device to the group and it connected with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/palantir/windows-event-forwarding/issues/37

This referenced the IPV6 option being disabled, just go into the collector and add the option in the registry for the ipv6.